# The output of bitmap always show null in android form

Tags: android, bitmap, upload

I have problem with java class android for upload a file to a remote server.

In the form I select the file on gallery image on smartphone, but the output of bitmap always show null and the form start is blocked.

```
Log.d("HomeActivity.class", "Output: " + bitmap);
```

This is beginning to make me believe my structure as a whole is not correct.

What am I missing ?

What's wrong with the code?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnSend;
    Spinner area;
    EditText description;
    ImageView viewImage;
    Button b, upload;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        viewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        area = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner_new);
        description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (area.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()
                        .equalsIgnoreCase("Select area")) {
                    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Area.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (description.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
                    description.setError("description");
                } else if (bitmap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "pic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    Log.d("HomeActivity.class", "Output: " + bitmap);
                } else {
                    ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this,
                            "Uploading" + bitmap, "Please wait...", true);
                }
            }
        });

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String path = "http://localhost/list.txt";
                URL u = null;
                try {
                    u = new URL(path);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u
                            .openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.connect();
                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
                    final ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[5120 * 512];
                    in.read(buffer);
                    bo.write(buffer);
                    String s = bo.toString();

                    final Vector<String> str = new Vector<String>();
                    String[] line = s.split("\n");
                    int index = 0;
                    while (index < line.length) {
                        str.add(line[index]);
                        index++;
                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner_new);
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                    HomeActivity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, str);
                            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                            try {
                                bo.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }

    private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == 1) {

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString());

                for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {

                    if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                        f = temp;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                try {

                    BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);

                    viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    Log.d("HomeActivity.class", "Valore restituito: " + bitmap);

                    String path = android.os.Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator
                            + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                    f.delete();
                    OutputStream outFile = null;
                    File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                            .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        outFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                        outFile.flush();
                        outFile.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath,
                        null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image from gallery......******************.........",
                        picturePath + "");
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**edit#1**

```
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (area.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()
                .equalsIgnoreCase("Select area")) {
            Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "Area.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (description.getText().toString().length() <= 0) {
            description.setError("description");
        } else if (bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "pic", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            Log.d("HomeActivity.class", "Output: " + bitmap);
        } else {
            ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this,
                    "Uploading" + bitmap, "Please wait...", true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 95% of questions on Android would not exist if people learned how to use the debugger.  For simple debugging, it's really simple.  Probably takes 30 minutes.  Step through your code with the debugger with breakpoints in each method.  You will quickly find the source of the problem.

Comment: thank you, but I have used the debugger, for debugger I know that bitmap is null in java class ...

Comment: So it's null here? `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                            bitmapOptions);`

Comment: I don't have output in debug for this.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line, step over it, what value does `bitmap` have?

Comment: I have added breakpoint on line bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),                             bitmapOptions); but I don't have output ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61753/discussion-between-antonio-mailtraq-and-simon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are starting your upload thread in onCreate. And so bitmap is null. Better start your thread in an onClick handler.

By the way: `Log.d("HomeActivity.class", "Output: " + bitmap);`. That is awfull trying to print a bitmap. If you want to check if the bitmap is null the do so:

```
 if ( bitmap==null )
     Log.d(TAG, "bitmap==null");
 else
     Log.d(TAG, "we have a nice bitmap");
```

Comment: thank you, but the thread upload is in an onClick handler. Please read edit#1 in the question

Comment: ??? No. I see no thread in the code block of edit#1. Put the thread in onClick. Your app starts already uploading when the activity is created. Is this what you want? I think you only want it to upload when the user clicks!?

Comment: Yes Sir. I need start to upload when the user clicks and the bitmap is not null

Comment: Ok. Then move that thread to the onClick handler. (third time asked).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what should I do ... I need check in the form before the upload the values of spinner area, edittext description and the bitmap is not null... I have to move in the onClick handler only bitmap check? I have to move all controls?